# How to integrate php code in a wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to develop a form that lets the user insert data, then store the data in the database and display the data in the admin panel.
I am looking for the right way to integrate it with WordPress.

I read about shortcodes, custom template or developing a plugin.

- A custom template will not be good for me since I want to use the theme template page.

What way should I choose for this specific development? shortcode or a plugin? what is the difference between them?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you pushing the data in custom post type or custom table?

Comment: @FahamShaikh I didn't really think about it. I guess it is a whole different question for me. What will be the difference in choosing one way on the other?

Comment: without that knowledge answering correctly is impossible as the code in each case will be different. On a side note, you can create shortcode or template in both theme as well as a plugin so that is your choice based upon the specifics of your theme.